# Prevent Google image search from associating images with incorrect pages because of their use in the "related products" section?

Tags: images, google-image-search

I have a page with a product and on the bottom have a block with cards where similar products. Google indexing this page and added for this page images from similar cards, but I'm not needed this, because it's wrong. For example, I'm searching in google images "product A" and getting results in pictures with "product B" and link send me to "product A".

Options for the expected result: either they are not indexed at all, or they are indexed but are attached to the page to which this card leads

Markup card:

```
<a href="/other-article">
  <img src="other-article.jpg" alt="Other article" />
  <h3>Other article</h3>
</a>
```

Comment: Are you using full sized images in this related products section or smaller thumbnails?   If you are using thumbnails what are examples of the thumbnail URL for an image compared to its full sized version?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, full version, as is in "product B". 384x384
ps: Thanks for your edits!